# How to select particular items in an array and form a new array using ES6 JS /Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

For example this is the original array:

```js
const animals = [{
    name: "Lion",
    image: "a url",
    gender: "male",
    age: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "Lion",
    image: "a url",
    gender: "male",
    age: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "Lion",
    image: "a url",
    gender: "male",
    age: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "Lion",
    image: "a url",
    gender: "male",
    age: "6"
  },
  {
    name: "Tiger",
    image: "a url",
    gender: "male",
    age: "6"
  },
]
```

I want to form a new array that holds only unique datas & consisiting of only name and image

So the new array should look like

```js
const newArray = [{
    name: "Lion",
    image: "a url"
  },
  {
    name: "Tiger",
    image: "a url"
  }

]
```

how can I form this newArray using less amount of code particularly using ES6 JS or using lodash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`_.uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy) to get the distinct values, and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) to get just the props you want:

```js
const animals = [{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"2"},{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"3"},{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"4"},{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"6"},{"name":"Tiger","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"6"}];

const result = _.uniqBy(animals, 'name').map((o) => _.pick(o, ['name', 'image']));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use object destructuring and `Map` to get unique values,  and spread element to convert `Map` instance to an array

```js
const animals = [{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"2"},{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"3"},{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"4"},{"name":"Lion","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"6"},{"name":"Tiger","image":"a url","gender":"male","age":"6"}];

let map = new Map;

animals.forEach(({name, image}) => {
 !map.has(name) && map.set(name, {name, image})
});

let res = [...map.values()];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and findIndex to get unique values:

```js
const animals = [
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "2"
},
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "3"
},
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "4"
},
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "6"
},
{
name: "Tiger",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "6"
},
];

console.log(animals.reduce((p,c)=>{
  if(p.findIndex(e=>e.name === c.name) === -1){
    p.push({
      name: c.name,
      image: c.image,
    });
  }
  return p;
},[]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even do this:

```js
const data = _.uniqBy(animals, 'name').map((K) => {
         return { name: K.name, image: K.image };
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const animals = [
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "2"
},
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "3"
},
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "4"
},
{
name: "Lion",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "6"
},
{
name: "Tiger",
image: "a url",
gender: "male",
age: "6"
},
]

// ES6 Style

const newAnimals = new Set()

animals.forEach(e=>{
  const { name, image } = e

  const animal = { name, image }
  if(newAnimals.size == 0){
    newAnimals.add(animal)
  }

  for(let a of newAnimals){
    console.log(a.name)
    if(a.name == name){
      console.log("animal already added.")
    } else {
      newAnimals.add(animal)
    }
  }
})
console.log([...newAnimals])
```

http://jsbin.com/yavodovawe/1/edit?console